# Obtain function from string in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to define a function to behave as follows?

```
text = "def x(a):\treturn a+1"
f = ??(text)
f(1)
>> 2
```

Comment: @BhargavRao I think that's the question...

Comment: Just `exec("print 'hello'")` or any other

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If the reasoning is "because I want to define a function on the same line that I use it, and `def` can't be on the same line as other statements", then you can instead use lambdas: `print (lambda a: a+1)(1)`

Comment: @Kevin I am creating an API where the user can define functions that would be executed by other function (which are actually lambdas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exec()`

```
text = "def x(a):\treturn a+1"
exec(text)
print x(5) # gives 6
```

Comment: Now the hard part is, getting `f(5)` to give 6, when you don't know the contents of `text` and don't know that the function is currently called `x`, and so you can't just do `f = x`

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "lambda a: a + 1"
f = eval(text)
f(1)    # 2
```

Comment: @bhargavrao: _any_ method of running arbitrary code is dangerous.

Comment: @forcebru: yes, that's why I converted it to a lambda!

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution:

```
text = "def x(a):\treturn a+1"
f = {}
exec text in f
f['x'](1)
>> 2
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.